# Function that takes a function and list and returns Boolean

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I am relatively new to Scala functional programming. I have been following a few tasks, however, finding difficult to understand or implement the concept below.

Basically, I want write a function which takes a list and a function, and returns true if the function returns true for at least one
item in the list. An example would be: hasMatch(isEven,List(1,2,3,5)) will return true, but hasMatch(isEven,List(1,3,5)) will return false.

A sample solution or hint is provided with the problem, as seen below:

```
def hasMatch (fn:(Int)=>Boolean,lst:List[Int]):Boolean = {
    lst.foreach ((x:Int) => if (fn(x)) return true)
return false
}
```

Could someone please explain the concept behind it or ways to implement it.

Comment: What is that you do not understand?

Comment: On how I could pass the list and apply the check for even numbers using functional programming in Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your isEven function is going to determine the outcome of the hasMatch function. So assuming that your isEven function is defined like this:

```
def isEven(x: Int): Boolean = x % 2 == 0
```

You can now define your hasMatch function like this:

```
def hasMatch(fn: Int => Boolean, l: List[Int]): Boolean = {
  l.exists(elem => fn(elem))
}
```

You then call the function like this:

```
hasMatch(isEven, List(1,2,3,5))
```

Comment: In this case, how would you pass your list containing your integers to perform the check?

Answer (score 1):

```
def hasMatch(fn: Int => Boolean, lst: List[Int]): Boolean = lst.exists(fn)
```

The `exists` function has the same semantics as what you're after - it returns true if fn returns true for at least one element, false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with your implementation: `return` is a really bad thing in scala, and should (almost) never be used.

Also, there are more idiomatic ways to do what you want, rather than spelling out the imperative loop with `foreach`.

Here is one possibility:

```
  def hasMatch[T](lst: List[T])(fn: T => Boolean) = lst.exists(fn)
```

I added a type parameter to your definition, so that it works for any type, not just `Int`. Also, I made `fn` the last argument, and moved it into a separate list. It makes it easier to pass anonymous functions in:

```
  if (hasMatch(List(1,2,3,4,5)) { _ > 5 }) println("There are elements greater than five")
```